# how to delete ag-grid row with a button in cell renderer

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

grid for CRUD application.
I've some data that shown in ag-grid table like this
[image: Ag-grid]

I've used ag-grid cell renderer to render that button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class DeleteButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span><button onClick={}>X</button></span>
        );
    }
}
```

I store the data and column defs in component's state like this

```
    this.state = {
        rewData : [
            {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", qty:12, price: 35000,  test:"", image:""},
            {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", qty:1, price: 32000,  test:"", image:""},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", qty:8, price: 72000, test:"", image:""},
            {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", qty:8, price: 72000,  test:"", image:""}
        ],
    columnDefs:[
{"headerName":"Make","field":"make","cellEditor":"textCellEditor","cellEditorParams":{"required":true}},
{"headerName":"Model","field":"model","cellEditor":"multiLineTextCellEditor","cellEditorParams":{"required":true}},
{"headerName":"Qty","field":"qty","cellEditor":"numericCellEditor","cellEditorParams":{"required":true}},
{"headerName":"Price","field":"price","cellEditor":"numericCellEditor","cellRenderer":"currencyCellRenderer","cellEditorParams":{"required":true}},
{"headerName":"test","field":"test","cellEditor":"manyToOneCellEditor","cellEditorParams":{"model":"account","host":"http://localhost:8282","fieldAsLabel":"name","fieldAsValue":"id","required":true}},
{"headerName":"image","field":"image","cellEditor":"fileUploadCellEditor","cellRenderer":"imageCellRenderer","cellEditorParams":{"required":true}},
{"headerName":"Delete","cellRenderer":"deleteButton"}
]
        }
```

and passed that in ag-grid's rowData props:

```
<AgGridReact
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
    rowData={this.state.rowData}
    onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
    onCellValueChanged={this.handleChange}
    frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
    singleClickEdit={true}
    stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus={true}
    reactNext={true}
/>
```

when I clicked the delete button, I want to delete corresponding row and also other things like validation or show notification to user, etc

how do i make that button works changing state of rowData?

where do i put the method to change rowData's state?

Comment: A lot of information is missing. How you are loading row data, If you click on delete, will it remove rows data from state or from db or something from where it was fetched. share more information like column definitions, cell renderer etc. then i could help you

Comment: hey, I've added some detailed code and conditions @SameerRezaKhan pls help

Comment: I just want to remove data from state, is there any other approach to delete row?

Comment: Call a function on click of button and pass the row data, as the row data is an object , you can find and delete object from this.state.rewData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.gridApi.updateRowData` will receive the `rowNode` in the array of object

```
export default class DeleteButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span><button onClick={() => this.buttonClick(this.props.node)}>X</button></span>
        );
    }
}
```

```
buttonClick = (e) => {

*// e is getting the current node (Row Node)*

        this.setState({
            visible:true
        })
        let deletedRow = this.props.node.data;
        e.gridApi.updateRowData({ remove: [deletedRow] })  // It will update the row
    };
```

Comment: I look in the documentation in  https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-api/ and there is no "e.gridApi.updateRowData" was there a change?

Comment: This api has now changed to - ```gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ remove: selectedData });```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `applyTransaction`.

**code**

```
if (param.data) param.api?.applyTransaction({ remove: [param.data] });
```

**full cell**

```
{
  field: 'Status & Actions',
  cellRenderer: (param: ICellRendererParams<IVdo>) => {
    param.api?.applyTransaction({ remove: [param.data] });
    return (<h1>My text</h1>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with the same case, and with the version 25.1.0 of ag-grid it works fine by using the applyTransaction as bellow :

```
buttonClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({visible:true})
    let deletedRow = this.props.node.data;
    e.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [deletedRow] })// It will update the row
};
```